# split stored value using JS in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, javascript

I am trying to use js split in one of my tests.  I need to store a url and save the last part of the url in a log file.  I have stored the url successfully but I can't get the slit to work.  So far I have the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>&quot;http://www.exampleUrl.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/-|845290&quot;</td>
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${a}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var pathArray = location.pathname.split( '-|' ); var a= pathArray[1];</td>
    <td>new</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${new}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

But when ever I run it I am getting an echo = null.

Comment: Can you echo location.pathname?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nope i still get the same response echo:null

Answer (score 2):

remove the assignments:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>location.pathname.split( '-|' )[1]</td>
    <td>new</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. Nope that didnt work either still the same result  echo: null

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code

```
store | http://www.exampleUrl.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/-|845290 | URL
store | 1 | delimiter
store | javascript{storedVars['URL'].split('/-|')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | result
echo  | ${result}
```

Result will be  - 845290